# Parse excel data to xml using java

Tags: java, xml, excel

I have the code below which reads excel files and displays it in java.
I'd like to implement the code after reading the data from the excel file to java, it will to convert in XML format and save it on XML file.

Any code sample or reference will be thankful;

```
public class POIExcelReader {

    public POIExcelReader (){
    }

    public void displayFromExcel (String xlsPath)
    {
        InputStream inputStream = null; 
        try
        {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream (xlsPath);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println ("File not found in the specified path.");
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

        POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = null;

        try {
            fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem (inputStream);
            HSSFWorkbook      workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fileSystem);
            HSSFSheet         sheet    = workBook.getSheetAt (0);
            Iterator<?> rows     = sheet.rowIterator ();

            while (rows.hasNext ())
            {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();

                // display row number
                System.out.println ("Row No.: " + row.getRowNum ());

                // get a row, iterate through cells.
                Iterator<?> cells = row.cellIterator ();

                while (cells.hasNext ())
                {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next ();
                    //System.out.println ("Cell : " + cell.getCellNum ());
                    switch (cell.getCellType ())
                    {
                    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC :
                    {
                        // NUMERIC CELL TYPE
                        System.out.println ("Numeric: " + cell.getNumericCellValue ());
                        break;
                    }
                    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING :

                    {
                        // STRING CELL TYPE
                        HSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell.getRichStringCellValue ();

                        System.out.println ("String: " + richTextString.getString ());
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        // types other than String and Numeric.
                        System.out.println ("Type not supported.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        POIExcelReader poiExample = new POIExcelReader ();
        String xlsPath ="c://Users//Secured//Desktop//artikli.xls";
        poiExample.displayFromExcel (xlsPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into XPath? I used it for a project before and it's really intuitive and malleable for many sets of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the classes in the package: javax.xml.parsers. The package provides classes allowing the processing of XML documents. e.g. DocumentBuilder, DocumentBuilderFactory, to mention a few.

Using the java code (extended your original code) below and the file located in this location: http://base.google.com/base/products.xls

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class POIExcelReader {

public POIExcelReader (){
}

public void displayFromExcel (String xlsPath)
{
    InputStream inputStream = null; 
    try
    {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream (xlsPath);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println ("File not found in the specified path.");
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }

    POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = null;

    try {
        //Initializing the XML document
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = document.createElement("products");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);


        fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem (inputStream);
        HSSFWorkbook      workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fileSystem);
        HSSFSheet         sheet    = workBook.getSheetAt (0); 
        Iterator<?> rows     = sheet.rowIterator ();

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        while (rows.hasNext ()) 
        {
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next(); 

            int rowNumber = row.getRowNum ();
            // display row number
            System.out.println ("Row No.: " + rowNumber);

            // get a row, iterate through cells.
            Iterator<?> cells = row.cellIterator (); 

            ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (cells.hasNext ())
            {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next ();
                //System.out.println ("Cell : " + cell.getCellNum ());
                switch (cell.getCellType ())
                {
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC :
                {
                    // NUMERIC CELL TYPE
                    System.out.println ("Numeric: " + cell.getNumericCellValue ());
                    rowData.add(cell.getNumericCellValue () + "");
                    break;
                }
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING :

                {
                    // STRING CELL TYPE
                    HSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell.getRichStringCellValue ();

                    System.out.println ("String: " + richTextString.getString ());
                    rowData.add(richTextString.getString ());
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    // types other than String and Numeric.
                    System.out.println ("Type not supported.");
                    break;
                }
                } // end switch

            } // end while
            data.add(rowData);


        } //end while

        int numOfProduct = data.size();

        for (int i = 1; i < numOfProduct; i++){
            Element productElement = document.createElement("product");
            rootElement.appendChild(productElement);

            int index = 0;
            for(String s: data.get(i)) {
                String headerString = data.get(0).get(index);
                if( data.get(0).get(index).equals("image link") ){
                    headerString = "image_link";
                }

                if( data.get(0).get(index).equals("product type") ){
                    headerString = "product_type";
                }

                Element headerElement = document.createElement(headerString);
                productElement.appendChild(headerElement);
                headerElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
                index++;
            }
        }

        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        //Add indentation to output
        transformer.setOutputProperty
        (OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(
                "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("products.xml"));
        //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("ParserConfigurationException " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("TransformerConfigurationException "+ e.getMessage());
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        System.out.println("TransformerException " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    POIExcelReader poiExample = new POIExcelReader ();
    String xlsPath ="products.xls";
    poiExample.displayFromExcel (xlsPath);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it!.
Another question, when the code retrieves the data from excel it adds a '.0'. how can I omit that? to retrieve it as original number (integer).. Thank you

Comment: Moreover, how can I avoid the warning message?:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: @n1ckgun set cell type as String before reading that cell . it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;


public class MyExp {
protected DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = null;
protected DocumentBuilder domBuilder = null;

public MyExp(){
    try {
        domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (FactoryConfigurationError exp) {
        System.err.println(exp.toString());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException exp) {
        System.err.println(exp.toString());
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        System.err.println(exp.toString());
    }
}
public void convertFile(String xlsFileName, String xmlFileName){

    try {
        Document newDoc = domBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = newDoc.createElement("XMLCreators");
        newDoc.appendChild(rootElement);
        InputStream InputStream=new FileInputStream(new File(xlsFileName));
        HSSFWorkbook      workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (InputStream);
        HSSFSheet         sheet    = workBook.getSheetAt (0); 
        Iterator<?> rows     = sheet.rowIterator ();
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>(5);
        while (rows.hasNext ()) 
        {
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next(); 

            int rowNumber = row.getRowNum ();
            Iterator<?> cells = row.cellIterator (); 
            ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (cells.hasNext ())
            {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next ();
                switch (cell.getCellType ())
                {
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC :
                {
                    // NUMERIC CELL TYPE
                    rowData.add(cell.getNumericCellValue () + "");
                    break;
                }
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING :

                {
                    // STRING CELL TYPE
          HSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
                    rowData.add(richTextString.getString ());
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
              }



            } // end while
            if(rowNumber==1){
                headers.addAll(rowData);
            }
            else
            {
                    Element rowElement = newDoc.createElement("row");
                    rootElement.appendChild(rowElement);
                    for (int col = 0; col < headers.size(); col++) {

                        String header = headers.get(col);
                        String value = null;

                        if (col < rowData.size()) {

                            value = rowData.get(col);

                        } else {
                            value = "";
                        }

                        Element curElement = newDoc.createElement(header);
                       curElement.appendChild(newDoc.createTextNode(value));
                        rowElement.appendChild(curElement);

                    }

            }

        } //end while

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

        try {

            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(baos);

          TransformerFactory tranFactory = ransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
            aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
          aTransformer.setOutputProperty("http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

            Source src = new DOMSource(newDoc);
            Result result = new StreamResult(new File(xmlFileName));
            aTransformer.transform(src, result);

            osw.flush();
            System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()));

        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                osw.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                baos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    MyExp poiExample = new MyExp ();
    poiExample.convertFile("srcfile.xls", "destfile.xml");
}
```

}