# how to read excel sheet from config file and access it in webdriver

Tags: webdriver, excel-2010, configuration-files

I need to access the excel sheet by storing it in config file and call the excel instead of hard coding the excel sheet path in selenium webdriver. what i need to achieve is: 1.store my excel sheet in config file. 
2.call the excel sheet when i want to access.
please suggest some ways through which this can be possible.

Comment: What is the config file exactly? Please elaborate.

Comment: It can be an XML file where i can store my excel sheet path and can call it whenever required. can you tel me how can i read that xml in java code

Answer (score 0):

You have to parts for your question.

**Part 1 - Excel file to XML**

Use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) libraries for reading in the Excel file ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357610/parse-excel-data-to-xml-using-java)).

Creating XML file is simple, either just write the XML out to a file directly, or append to an already existing XML Document and then write that out using the standard Java libs or Xerces or similar.

**Part 2 - Accessing the XML**

The same as above, use the Apache POI libraries. [Code example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/).